# Why fetch returns promise pending?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I am using fetch to get data but it keeps returning promise as pending. I've seen many posts regarding this issue and tried all the possibilities but didn't solve my issue. I wanted to know why the fetch returns promise as pending in brief what are the possible cases where fetch returns pending status?

My piece of code for reference:

```
fetch(res.url).then(function(u){ 
    return u.json();
})
.then(function(j) { 
    console.log(j); 
});
```

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it return a pending Promise? And why is it an issue? A fetch will issue a network request, it's non-blocking, hence async.

Comment: Sorry, which part is the promise pending? `console.log(j);` ? or something else?

Comment: A promise will *always* be `pending` at first

Comment: It's async so it has to return a pending promise that you can then resolve/reject

Comment: Suppose you send me to the store to get some milk.  Until I return with the milk, that job is pending.  Upon my return, it is completed.  It's the same with JS promises.  You're sending a request to a remote server.  Until that requested data is returned, is is pending.  Once the data is back, it is completed.

Comment: When I'm printing the data in the console it keeps returning the same promise as pending. What does that mean? @voiys

Comment: @SPL do you mean the `console.log(j)`? And are you *sure* it happens there? Because if you just do this in the console, the first thing that will print is the *return value of `fetch.then().then()`*. That return value is a Promise that is still pending at the time.

Comment: If you're printing data (I assume, `j`) in the console, the Promise is not pending, because you are inside the `then`, and you have data to log, so the call is finished. I don't understand the problem

Comment: `console.log` isn't fed a promise, but an already resolved value. But if you do `fetch(url).then(doStuff).then(console.log)` in the console, then yes, the first thing you should see is `Promise {<pending>}`. That's expected and correct.

Comment: Yeah I got that. It keeps loading and not entering the next _then_ .Is it the url fault? @VLAZ

Comment: And what is going on in the Network tab?

Comment: @SPL maybe? Are there any errors/warnings? CORS?

Comment: In my network it is showing as pending and I'm getting an error `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON` @VLAZ @mbojko

Comment: Then what you get is *not* JSON, so `u.json()` throws that error.

Comment: That's the API.  `fetch()` returns a Promise.  `.json()` returns a Promise.  The reason it returns a Promise is because that's the API.  `XMLHttpRequest` deals in events and callbacks.  If you want a different API, use a different function.

Comment: user 47589: THAT is the way to answer a question as it explains it in everyday terms that "noobs" can also understand. Not everyone is a high brow web designer as some of SO respondents sometime believe (Some replies leave the user more baffled than when they started as the reply shows off the respondent`s technical prowess !)

Answer (score 20):

As one of the upper comments said, `fetch()` is a promise that calls `.then()` when the request is handled by the network. The parameter in this callback is another promise that calls `$.then()` when we get the response from the server.

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
fetch(res.url)
    .then(function(serverPromise){ 
      serverPromise.json()
        .then(function(j) { 
          console.log(j); 
        })
        .catch(function(e){
          console.log(e);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(e){
        console.log(e);
      });
```

or in lambda notation:

```
fetch(res.url)
    .then((serverPromise) => 
      serverPromise.json()
        .then((j) => console.log(j))
        .catch((e) => console.log(e))
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

This is the first time I post here in StackOverflow, so please let me know if I made any mistake or you have any sugestions, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

A `fetch()` is a network operation. To avoid hanging until we get a reply from the network, we defer it to the background and give ourselves the promise that it will complete eventually.

So `fetch(url).then((data) => data.json())` means that we fetch the url, wait for data to come in, get the json representation of the data and wait for that too (data.json() is a promise too)

Until we get a result, the promise is in the `pending` state. The server hasn't replied to our request yet.

-- 
Reading the comments, it might be nice to add a error handler as that is why the current fetch is supposedly not doing anything:
`fetch().then((data) => data.json()).catch((error) => console.log(error))`

Comment: or better switch to using async/await `async foo() { try { const res = await fetch(); const result = await res.json(); } catch (e) { console.log.error; } ); foo();`

Comment: Also a possibility. Makes it more easy to read but OP was using `.then` chaining so I followed his example

Comment: I wasn't critquing your answer. I was suggesting another solution to the questioner. I find async/await far eaiser to use than `.then` so I when I see I user struggling with `.then` I generally suggest switching to async/await. It's just easier overall IMO.

Comment: I did not take it as a critique and I agree with your statement here too :)

Comment: Your **(data.json() is a promise too)** save me a lot of time hahah I did not know that

Answer (score 11):

[Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are a way to allow callers do other work while waiting for result of the function.

See [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) on MDN:

> A Promise is in one of these states:
>
> - pending: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
> - fulfilled: meaning that the operation completed successfully.
> - rejected: meaning that the operation failed.

The `fetch(url)` returns a `Promise` object. It allows attaching “listener” to it using `.then(…)` that can respond to result value (response to the request). The `.then(…)` returns again `Promise` object that will give result forward.

## `async` and `await`

You can use JS syntax sugar for using Promises:

```js
async function my_async_fn(url) {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response); // Logs the response
    return response;
)

console.log(my_async_fn(url)); // Returns Promise
```

`async function`s return a Promise. `await` keyword wraps rest of the function in `.then(…)`. Here is equivalent without `await` and `async`:

```js
// This function also returns Promise
function my_async_fn(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(response => {
        console.log(response); // Logs the response
        return response;
    });
)

console.log(my_async_fn(url)); // Returns Promise
```

Again see [article on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) on MDN.