# fetch repeatedly returns pending promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, fetch

I need to request data from my REST server to populate my UI (frontend). In doing so, I need to request some data from my and other servers. One such request is to get a list of states (provinces). I use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) to do this.

I see there are a few questions on SO addressing this issue mentioned below ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59394620/why-fetch-returns-promise-pending), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228574/using-javascript-fetch-returns-pending-promise) and a few more), however attempting their solutions/suggestions did not solve my problem.

e.g.

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces").then(e => e.json()).then(console.log);
```

Naturally `fetch()` being a network operation returns a promise, or I can use it with `await` & `async`. Also, `.json()` is also a promise. Since `then()` is called by [resolve(data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) to proceed to the next [then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) and `.catch(error)` processes [reject(error)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject), the request above should make sense.

**Problem:**

However, on each call to:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces")
    .then(e => e.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.warn);
```

I get a `Promise {<pending>}`. Since it is the case, I tried the same with an `async/await` impl and receive the same "error":

```
(async () => {
    let l = await fetch("http://localhost:3443/app/location/provinces");
    console.log(l);
})();
```

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: Thats not an error. Its your REPL showing the result of the last expression.

Comment: @tkausl so strange, simply pressing up and running the exact same request again works (all the time, the rest server has been running on localhost)...eh?

Comment: The await version is missing another await for `let data = await l.json()`. The then version looks fine

Comment: @charlietfl quite right indeed, thanks for the addition

Comment: So, `fetch()` returns a pending promise.  That's what it does.  And `fetch().then()` returns a pending promise.  You have to either use the result inside a `.then()` handler or use `await` on that pending promise to get the value from it.